# Writng an interface to import data from one storage system to an other

Tags: php, mysql, oop, google-docs-api, php-deployer

Please can someone help me with the following problem.

The problem is 
"I need to to write an interface to import  data stored in various "storage systems", like Google Docs, MySQL DB and export them to my storage system.

My storage system is not yet defined it could be anything ..
This interface will be later implemented.

I am  not very sure what all is needed for this interface . 
Should the interface have all the CURD operation only 
and what kind of parameters should i pass ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can can't implement methods in side interface.

Just declare the body of method and inherite interface in other class and implement that method